# Nginx 404 Not Found

Tags: linux, nginx, php, http-status-code-404

I have the problem that my http://kd41364.zap-hosting.com/ Webpage
works on my Linux. However, all other sub-pages get a 404 Not Found error from nginx. (www.kd41364.zap-hosting.com/owncloud)
I tried everythink from this forum and a lot of other thinks but nothing works.

nginx.conf

```
    user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections 2048;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 70;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;
    # server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 4000M;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /etc/nginx/logs/access.log;
    error_log /etc/nginx/logs/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css
                      application/x-javascript text/xml
                      application/xml application/xml+rss
                      text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger

    #passenger_root /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby;

    ##
    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/pages/*;
    include /etc/nginx/confs/*;

}
```

nginx error.log

```
2015/11/25 17:29:39 [emerg] 236#0: open() "/etc/nginx/logs/access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2015/11/25 17:30:17 [warn] 961#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:51
2015/11/25 17:30:17 [emerg] 961#0: open() "/etc/nginx/logs/access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2015/11/25 17:34:09 [warn] 1560#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:51
2015/11/25 17:34:09 [emerg] 1560#0: open() "/etc/nginx/logs/access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2015/11/25 17:35:00 [warn] 1601#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:51
2015/11/25 17:35:00 [emerg] 1601#0: open() "/etc/nginx/logs/access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2015/11/25 17:36:54 [warn] 1651#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:51
2015/11/25 17:36:54 [warn] 1654#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:51
2015/11/25 18:08:01 [warn] 1844#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:51
2015/11/25 18:08:01 [warn] 1847#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:51
2015/11/25 18:26:34 [warn] 256#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:51
2015/11/25 18:26:34 [warn] 278#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:51
2015/11/26 12:23:48 [warn] 178#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:51
2015/11/26 12:23:48 [warn] 222#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:51
2015/11/26 12:25:42 [warn] 256#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:51
2015/11/25 16:31:20 [warn] 255#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:51
2015/11/25 16:31:20 [emerg] 255#0: unknown directive "passenger_root" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:66
2015/11/25 16:42:41 [warn] 1087#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:51
2015/11/25 16:42:41 [emerg] 1087#0: unknown directive "passenger_root" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:66
2015/11/25 16:43:16 [warn] 1121#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:51
2015/11/25 16:43:16 [emerg] 1121#0: unknown directive "passenger_root" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:66
2015/11/25 16:47:22 [warn] 1155#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:51
2015/11/25 16:47:22 [emerg] 1155#0: open() "/etc/nginx/logs/access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2015/11/25 17:09:33 [warn] 1301#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:51
2015/11/25 17:09:33 [emerg] 1301#0: open() "/etc/nginx/logs/access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2015/11/25 17:12:13 [warn] 1336#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:51
2015/11/25 17:12:13 [emerg] 1336#0: open() "/etc/nginx/logs/access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2015/11/25 17:23:28 [warn] 238#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:51
2015/11/25 17:23:28 [emerg] 238#0: open() "/etc/nginx/logs/access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2015/11/25 17:24:46 [warn] 962#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:51
2015/11/25 17:24:46 [emerg] 962#0: open() "/etc/nginx/logs/access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2015/11/25 17:29:39 [warn] 236#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:51
```

vhost config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name kd41364.zap-hosting.com www.kd41364.zap-hosting.com;

    root /var/www/;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;

    include includes/favicon.conf;
    include includes/cgi.conf;
    include includes/php.conf;

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    } 
}
```

Unfortunately I have no idea what you need to help me, so please ask me and i will upload it.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Add some more information in the question. Put your nginx.conf in here, but the relevant contents of the log file in here. Put your sites config in here. Let us know what you have done rather then I've done everything

Comment: updatet, if y need anymore just say it.

Comment: you need to show the vhost config not the main server config

Comment: and where can i find it

Comment: @SunnyTeater: It's a file inside `/etc/nginx/conf.d/ or `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`.

Comment: @Mike updated..

Answer (score 2):

I came across this problem also - `text/html` is always compressed by HttpGzipModule, so you don't need to include it in the list of gzip_types.

If you change your gzip types line to:

```
gzip_types text/plain text/css
           application/x-javascript text/xml
           application/xml application/xml+rss
           text/javascript;
```

Your error will go away.

I also notice that you don't seem to want to log access.log - if this is the case add this line also:

```
access_log off;
```